# C++ header/source files in file chooser

Tags: vim, gvim

By convention, our C++ headers live in `.hpp` files. When I open a gvim window with a `.cpp` file (so C++ source), then use the open menus, I get file chooser window which allows me to select files for:

- C++ Source Files (*.cpp, *.c++)
- C Header Files (*.h)
- C Source Files (*.c)
- All Files (*.*)

Clearly, none of those will match just C++ Headers -- whatever the extension is. So, my question is:

*How do I create a new entry for C++ Header Files (*.hpp, *.h++)?*

**Bonus**: *How do I add (*) to the All Files option?* I guess this will be the same method as above.

Comment: those entries are not default, if you have cpp file in the current directory it adds itself C++ files and all.

Comment: @VivianMaya: Okay, not default but something must decide what to add to the list.  Once I know that, I can probably work out how to add my own defaults to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be configured via a buffer-local `b:browsefilter` variable, which is set in *filetype plugins*; for C/C++, `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/c.vim`. To change / override this, just put the following into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim`:

```
let b:browsefilter = "C++ Source Files (*.cpp *.c++)\t*.cpp;*.c++\n" .
  \ "C Header Files (*.hpp, *.h++)\t*.hpp;*.h++\n" .
  \ "C Source Files (*.c)\t*.c\n" .
  \ "All Files (*.*)\t*.*\n"
```

Comment: That is **AWESOME**!!! ^_^ Many thanks indeed.

Comment: Cool :) I didn't think there was anyway out of the hardcoded value when I looked at source.  Guess I was wrong!